# Showing a polynomial f of degree $\le n$ can be written as a linear combination of lin. ind. polys of deg $\le n$

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods

I'm studying for my qual in scientific computing and the text book I am looking through has this theorem with no proof:

Suppose that $\phi_0, \ldots , \phi_n$ is a collection of linear independent polynomials of degree at most $n$. Then any polynomial of degree at most $n$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination of $\{\phi_i\}$'s

This is one of those things where I think I use to know how to show it but I no longer do. I've tried to look it up online but of I just find results in terms of vectors. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

My intuition says that for the collection of $\phi_i$'s to be independent polynomials of degree less than $n$ than one will have to be degree 0, degree 1, ..., degree n and then I can argue determining the coefficents of the linear combination by the starting with the largest coefficient of the given polynomial and working backwards. But this seems convoluted and I imagine there is a quick and clear way to do it.
Thanks!

*EDIT
It just occurred to me that induction would probably be pretty straight forward. Is that the best approach?

Comment: A collection of $n+1$ linearly indep. polynomials all of degree $\le n$ need not have one of each degree.

Comment: The set of polynomials of degree at most $n$ forms a $n+1$ dimensional vector space. Since $\{\phi_0,\ \phi_1,\ \cdots,\ \phi_n\}$ is a set of $n+1$ linearly independent vectors in the vector space, they necessarily a basis. This is intrinsically a linear algebraic result, approaching it without using vectors seems a bit awkward.

Comment: @ Andre, Can you explain why it need not have one of each degree? From EuYu's answer it seems like it would have to have a polynomial of each degree. ie consider the function $x^k$ for any $k le n$. could it be written as a linear combination of the $\phi_i$'s unless there is a term of degree k? Is it that for each k there need not be a single $\phi_j$ with degree k?